# Weight training for body re-composition

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss

I'm 5 '11 183 pounds and about 23% body fat. I'm new to working out and I'd like some help with a weight training (and cardio if needed) program. I'm looking to build on lean muscle mass and lose fat. Thank you!

Comment: This has been asked several times on the site, and is a very broad question as it is stated. If you could research a bit of what you want to do, and narrow it down other than "get more muscular", we can help you with better suggestions. Right now it would be "Eat healthy and do stronglifts or similar". :) Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to lifting just take something basic from the internet, your composition doesn't seem too alarming to overweight or underweight so if you just pick a plan and follow it with **Good form**(this is important) and push yourself, follow a diet plan and stay consistent with your training you're going to see results.

As someone who is new to training you just need to follow a plan that you will stick to and just start. Learn the form and stay strict with it.

If you google it, the information is there. Once you've been going for a few months if you want to be leaner then start your cardio and cutting but for now, just eat clean and train.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, I'd suggest to take an appointment with a coach, just to make a program that fits you and get started.

If you want to build muscle and lose fat on the same time, you will have to be careful on your diet, so seeing a nutritionist can be a nice thing too.

Be careful with internet : everybody is different. My diet is perfectly fine for me but not for a lot of people, it is the same for my workout.